# Is this regular expression correct?

Tags: java, regex

For a string like 2012ca-e001a083, I want to only parse e001a083 and I'm using a regular expression in Java like: `(.*-)(.*)` so I should be able to pull out "e001a083" in group = 2 correct ? Does this regex seem correct ?

Comment: Why the need for a regex? Just `split()` it at the `-`.

Comment: "Is this correct?" questions always seemed weird to me. Why not just... try it?

Comment: I can only use regex as I'm using an external api which only supports regex.

Comment: Then that should be stated as a constraint for an answer.

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ comes in handy when I have to test out a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can aether split on `-` and take last part, or pick second group of your regex like

```
String data="2012ca-e001a083";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(.*-)(.*)");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

But I would recommend to use split mechanism since backtracking in regex will be probably much slower.

---

There is also another option. You can use [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism. Then you wont need to point which group you want.

```
String data="2012ca-e001a083";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?<=-).*");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of what you are matching is very clearly defined, it is safer (and often more useful) to match the format as closely as possible...

```
(\d{4}[a-z]{2})-(([a-z]\d{3}){2})
```

which breaks down like this...

```
(        // start group 1
\d{4}    // four digits
[a-z]{2} // two letters (lowercase)
)        // close group 1
-        // hyphen
(        // start group 2
(        // start group 3 (repeats within group 2)
[a-z]    // letter
\d{3}    // three digits
){2}     // close group 3, matching when it repeats twice
)        // close group 2 (capturing the repeated group 3)
```

Group 1 should end up containing everything before the `-` and group 2 everything after

Answer (score 0):

While that RE would work and deliver the substring you want as the second group, you've got a poor RE there. In particular, you should avoid capturing groups if you don't need them and you should also make the first part able to be scanned exactly once rather than trying to backtrack. The RE `[^-]*-([^-]*)` is more suitable (in which case it will be the *first* group in the RE that is the thing you want) as that can parse correct strings in a single scan.

Comment: There's an art to writing a good RE: you have to think like a matcher automaton. That's a bit hard to explain if you've never done the requisite parts of CS, but the key is to ensure that the code always knows _exactly_ what it is doing…

Comment: Could you explain this regular expression ?